# undetected error probabilities in CRC and relation to link error rate

Tags: crc

How does the probability of undetected error **vary as a function of link type**? are they related at all?
I mean if the link is lossy or has a higher bit error rate **how this would affect** the Undetected Error Probability?
Is there **any formula** to calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really mean by "link type" is the error characteristics of the channel. On a channel with a high bit error rate, e.g. the number of bits in the CRC (*n*) in error somewhere in each message (where each messages gets a CRC), the usual undetected rate of 2<sup>-*n*</sup> per message applies. It is always at least this good. So there's your formula.

Assuming of course that the errors are random. It is possible to deliberately apply errors calculated to leave the CRC unchanged, so CRCs cannot protect against those with malicious intent.

However the undetected error probability can get better than that formula, for lower bit error rates.

Then it gets more complicated. If you *never* expect to get more than one-bit error in a message, then a CRC will *always* detect the error, regardless of the length of the message. (A CRC always provides a parity check.) If a CRC polynomial has a factor of *x+1*, then it will always detect an *odd* number of bit errors. CRCs also have special "burst" error properties that I won't get into. Let's assume that you have a bit error rate where any bit in the message can be flipped with that probability. (A [binary symmetric channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel).)

For a given number of error bits in the message, you find that there are finite message lengths for which that many errors (or fewer) will always be detected.

[This page](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/crc/crc32.html) shows those properties for many 32-bit CRC polynomials. As an example, can look at the entry for the usual 32-bit CRC with polynomial `0x04c11db7`. It has this cryptic list of numbers:

```
{4294967263,91607,2974,268,171,91,57,34,21,12,10,10,10}
```

Those numbers correspond respectively to 2, 3, 4, etc. error bits in a message. Each number is the length in bits of the longest message (not including the CRC) for which a CRC using that polynomial is guaranteed to detect that many errors.

So that CRC will always detect three or fewer bit errors in messages up to 91,607 bits in length. It will always detect four or fewer bit errors in messages up to 2,974 bits in length.

There is no simple formula in this case, as those numbers are the result of exhaustive searches for "codewords", which are patterns whose CRC is zero. Those can be seen as patterns of errors that can be applied to any message that result in no change to the CRC.

There are formulas to calculate the probability that a message of *n* bits has *k* or fewer errors, given a bit error rate of *p*. See the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), and its approximations.

Comment: You mentioned "the usual undetected rate of 2^(-n) per message applies. It is always at least this good", Is it possible that the higher bit error rate in the channel causes the CRC to be worse than that? or you mean even if we have all the bits in error but we can detect at lease 2^(-crc)

Comment: If you know the error pattern, in this case every single bit in the message flipped, and you know your message length, you can determine for certain whether the CRC will detect that error or not. So it's not a probability. If I consider my message _length_ to be the random variable, then yes, only one out of 2^32 message lengths will result in those errors not being detected. The first such message length is 2^32-1 bits, or a half-a-gigabyte-long message.

Comment: So if i got it correctly The PUE is not related to channel bit error. if I have 2 channels 1 with 10^(-3) and one with 10^(-15) Bit error rates, the PUE is always the same (**if the packet size is less than 512MB**).

Comment: You do not have it correct. It depends on the bit error rate and the packet size.

Comment: But it is not going to be worst than 2^(-CRC), right?

Comment: Is undetected error probability considered all undetected bursts? (for example in a 32-bit CRC if a burst more than a 32-bit flip happens it may not be detected by the CRC, is this considered in undetected error probability?)